# Leap Motion Python SDK with conda

Tags: python-2.7, sdk, anaconda, leap-motion, conda

I am using an anaconda's python 2.7 distribution as my default python distribution. I receive a 
`Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread`
This error seems to be a result of a python distribution conflict; I am using anconda's python distribution but Leap motion's sdk anticipates the default mac distribution.

I followed Leap motion's sdk instructions on [changing the default python distribution](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/devguide/Project_Setup.html) as follows,

`install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python 
//anaconda/bin/python LeapPython.so`

But now I receive the following error, which I have not been able to make much of,

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sample.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Leap, sys, thread, time
  File "/Users/jkarimi91/Documents/Projects/hackingedu/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/lib/Leap.py", line 28, in <module>
    LeapPython = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/jkarimi91/Documents/Projects/hackingedu/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/lib/Leap.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('LeapPython', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jkarimi91/Documents/Projects/hackingedu/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/lib/LeapPython.so, 2): Library not loaded: //anaconda/bin/python
  Referenced from: /Users/jkarimi91/Documents/Projects/hackingedu/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_mac/LeapSDK/lib/LeapPython.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    //anaconda/bin/python: can't map unslidable segment __TEXT to 0x100000000 with size 0x1000`

Comment: any progress on this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to load the Python executable, not the shared library. Since Anaconda doesn't seem to give you a framework, try replacing `/anaconda/bin/python` in your command with `/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.10.0` or if that doesn't work, specify the full path to the Python dylib  `/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.10.0/lib/libpython2.7.dylib`.